# Node js process on directory in docker container

Tags: node.js, linux, docker

I am running a node application in a docker container, and when i exec into the docker container and execute `ps -fea` I see all the node running processes as expected, (node app.js) but I noticed that there's a node process running on the application directory. I could not find what this means, does it mean child processes are running within that directory? My docker container is FROM node:latest official image.

My output of `ps -fea` on container:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root        15     1  0 23:29 ?        00:00:00 sh -c node app.js
root        16    15  1 23:29 ?        00:00:00 node app.js
root        26    16  1 23:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/node /usr/src/app
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the output you provide, the process you are asking about has a PID of 26 and a Parent PID (PPID) of 16. (That's all in the last line you provide.)

And 16 is the PID of your expected `node app.js` process. (That's in the line before the last one.)

So, yes, that process is a child process of your `node app.js` process.

I don't know that it's possible to say much more about it without knowing the contents of `app.js` and the modules it loads. (Although it's possible someone else has seen something similar and will have a better idea?)

Comment: I am assuming child processes in the app.js could be node js models that are loaded? Or other dependent files that app.js calls?